# passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast…can any body help me

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int count = 0;
    c=fgetc(file);
    while  (c != '\n' )
    {
        instruction_file[count] = atoi(c);
        c = fgetc(file);
        count++;
    }
}
```

The error message is

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/stdlib.h 147, expected const char* but argument of type char
```

Comment: check out `atoi`'s expected parameter type

Comment: You haven't told us what `instruction_file` is. Also, are you reading from a text file or a binary file?

Comment: The argument to atoi is an address, thus you can use ---- atoi(&c);

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey: that's not sufficient; `atoi` expects its argument to point to a *zero-terminated string*.  Just passing the address of a single `char` variable isn't correct.

Comment: @JohnBode : Definitely :-).

Comment: atoi() is expecting a pointer for its' parameter.  passing the char 'c' is not passing a pointer.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are trying to use `atoi` to parse single-digit numbers. However, since `atoi` expects a C string and takes a `const char*`, you cannot pass it a plain `char`. You need to pass it a properly terminated C string:

```
char c[2] = {0};
c[0]=fgetc(file);
instruction_file[count] = atoi(c); // This will compile
```

However, this is not the most efficient way of interpreting a digit as a numeric value: you can do the same thing faster by subtracting `0` from the digit:

```
char c;
...
instruction_file[count] = c - '0';
```

Comment: Although the concept of subtracting characters is not very intuitive, it is the way to go. Anything else is just a waste of time.

Comment: @stefan I completely agree. I included the `atoi` fix in case OP would want to switch to multi-digit numbers in later incarnations of his program.

Comment: For multi-digit numbers, reading character by character is ill-advised ;-) But I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` expects a `char *` for input. You are passing it a `char`, which is exactly what the warning message tells you. If you are certain that you only want a single character from your file, change the declaration of `c` to `char c[2];` and add `c[1]='\0';` after the lines `c=fgetc(file);`.

Comment: @user3386109 Righto: need to be paying more attention before hitting submit. Fixed now, I think.

Comment: yup, much better :) I removed the comment since no one can see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want convert a numeric character (digit) in an integer value you can use ASCII code offset:

```
int main()
{

    char c = '1';

    int i = c - '0'; // ASCII code offset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

c - '0'

atoi expects char pointer (string or array of char), but you pass the int

Answer (score 0):

By giving 'c' as argument to atoi you are passing an integer value (ascii value of c which    is 99), but the function atoi wants an null terminated array of characters (string),      precisely an address since it accepts a pointer variable as its argument.